# Connecting to TFS through Visual Studio 2008 makes me Administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

We are running TFS 2010 Beta 2 on the source control server. I am running Visual Studio 2008 Sp1 with the team explorer plus compatibility pack so that it can connect to 2010. Everything is fine!

I had connected to the server and setup my workspace, checked in all our source code and could make changes and check them in and it would associated the change set to me. Everything I thought was fine.

I had an issue today and it required me to attach to the iis worker process to debug a website, this is when the issues started. I had to restart Visual Studio as "Run as Administrator" to be able to do this, I continued on to develop the website in this mannor, everything was fine.

I got to a point and went to check it in, this is when I noticed something wasn't quite right ... the changeset was associated to Administrator and not me. I have tried restarting VS, without the "run as", and it still checks in changes to Administrator. The workspace is owned by Administrator and not me.

I am a local Admin on the machine.

**Question (Multipart):**

a) How can I get it to be me checking things in again?

b) How can I do (a) while still having the permissions of "Run as Administrator"?

c) Why did this happen and how can I stop this happening again?

I've been tearing out my hair (what little I have left) and re-mapping workspaces etc. all afternoon and it's been driving me mad! Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

**EDIT / UPDATE**
I've installed the [following](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/vista/add-runas-to-explorer-context-menu-in-vista-and-server-2008/) "Run as" script plug in on both my machine and the server where I have team foundation explorer installed. I have run it as me on my local machine and it still thinks I am the domain admin, however if I do a run as me on the server it knows it's me which has logged in. I've also tried installing VS 2010 on my local machine and that does the same. So, starting to think its something to do with my local profile ... :-/

Comment: Are you using Over The Shoulder (typing new credentials) or Admin Approval Mode to elevate VS?

Comment: I'm not typing new credentials. I'm really new to Vista/Windows 7 so not sure what Admin Approval Mode is? (was using windows xp till 2.5 weeks ago). I'm either right clicking the task bar icon, then right clicking "Mircosoft Visual Studio 2008" then "Run as administrator" or Ctrl+shift+left click to launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after searching around on the net, and the IT guy at working searching around on the net ... [this link was turned up](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsprofiler/thread/cd56aaa0-ff6e-40ae-b7e0-b0452ca3c40d) (thanks Joe!!). This was quite an interesting read and I learnt something about the password vault in windows 7. I had the domain admin username / password in my password vault, prolly not a great thing, but once it was removed ... it was fine!

Hope this helps someone else in the future.